# Using Moq the Start() method keeps retuning a null object

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I'm having trouble figuring out why I can't test my `driver` variable, it keeps coming back `null` with I call `Start()`. I basically would like to access that variable and test it.

My current test that isn't working:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Start_Default_IsChrome2()
{
    var dummyManager = new Mock<IRemoteDriver>();
    var mockDriver = new Mock<IWebDriver>();
    dummyManager.Setup(x => x.CreateRemoteWebDriver(new ChromeOptions()))
                .Returns(It.IsAny<RemoteWebDriver>());
    var session = new SauceSession(dummyManager.Object);
    //The Start() keeps returning a null object
    var driver = session.Start();
    var capabilities = driver.Capabilities;
    capabilities.GetCapability("browserName").Should().Be("chrome");
}
```

Dependency to be mocked

```
public interface IRemoteDriver
{
    IWebDriver CreateRemoteWebDriver(ChromeOptions chromeOptions);
}
```

Subject Under Test

```
public SauceSession(IRemoteDriver driverManager)
{
    remoteDriverManager = driverManager;
}



public RemoteWebDriver Start()
{
    sauceUserName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SAUCE_USERNAME", EnvironmentVariableTarget.User);
    sauceAccessKey = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SAUCE_ACCESS_KEY", EnvironmentVariableTarget.User);
    sauceOptions = new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        ["username"] = sauceUserName,
        ["accessKey"] = sauceAccessKey
    };

    var chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions
    {
        BrowserVersion = "latest",
        PlatformName = "Windows 10",
        UseSpecCompliantProtocol = true
    };
    chromeOptions.AddAdditionalCapability("sauce:options", sauceOptions, true);
    //This keeps returning a null
    return (RemoteWebDriver)remoteDriverManager.CreateRemoteWebDriver(chromeOptions);
}
```

If it helps, the Concrete implementation works just fine and that test looks like this:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void Start_Default_IsChrome()
    {
        var session = new SauceSession();
        var driver = session.Start();
        var capabilities = ((RemoteWebDriver)driver).Capabilities;
        capabilities.GetCapability("browserName").Should().Be("chrome");
    }
```

Everything else is the same except the object that I set here:

```
    public SauceSession()
    {
        remoteDriverManager = new ConcreteRemoteWebDriver();
    }

class ConcreteRemoteWebDriver : IRemoteDriver
{
    public IWebDriver CreateRemoteWebDriver(ChromeOptions chromeOptions)
    {
        return new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("https://ondemand.saucelabs.com/wd/hub"),
            chromeOptions.ToCapabilities(), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(600));
    }
}
```

Here's the RemoteWebDriver:

```
public class RemoteWebDriver : IWebDriver, ISearchContext, IDisposable, IJavaScriptExecutor, IFindsById, IFindsByClassName, IFindsByLinkText, IFindsByName, IFindsByTagName, IFindsByXPath, IFindsByPartialLinkText, IFindsByCssSelector, ITakesScreenshot, IHasInputDevices, IHasCapabilities, IHasWebStorage, IHasLocationContext, IHasApplicationCache, IAllowsFileDetection, IHasSessionId, IActionExecutor
```

Answer (score 2):

You've done your setup improperly.

```cs
dummyManager.Setup(x => x.CreateRemoteWebDriver(new ChromeOptions()))
            .Returns(It.IsAny<RemoteWebDriver>());
```

Two things here:

You're matching on precisely an instance of `new ChromeOptions()`. When determining which object to return, Moq will check if the arguments passed to `CreateRemoteWebDriver` are the same as the ones provided in the setup. It's unlikely that

```cs
new ChromeOptions
{
     BrowserVersion = "latest",
     PlatformName = "Windows 10",
     UseSpecCompliantProtocol = true
};
```

and

```cs
new ChromeOptions()
```

will evaluate as equal, meaning that this setup won't be matched.

You probably just meant to use `It.IsAny<ChromeOptions>()`, like this

```cs
dummyManager.Setup(x => x.CreateRemoteWebDriver(It.IsAny<ChromeOptions>()))
```

The second issue is that your return value is explicitly null.
`It.IsAny<T>()` always returns the default value for `T`. The `It` methods are all only used for argument matching within the `Setup` expression. If you use them outside of a setup expression, you're just going to get the default value of the generic argument, which in this case is a null value. It's a shame that the Moq library doesn't make this improper usage a loud error message. Consequently, you'll need to provide an actual instance of `RemoteWebDriver` as a return value. (Or if you can decouple the implementation from a particular concrete type, you could just return something that implements `IWebDriver`.)

That value could be another Mock object, potentially, but it needs to be something you've either created ahead of time, or something that can be created via the Returns callback.

A correct setup might look something like:

```cs
var mockDriver = new Mock<RemoteWebDriver>();
dummyManager.Setup(x => x.CreateRemoteWebDriver(It.IsAny<ChromeOptions>()))
            .Returns(mockDriver.Object); //This could throw an exception if RemoteWebDriver needs arguments.
```

A small caveat is that you will *actually* create a `RemoteWebDriver` instance as a result. If that has undesirable side effects (such as creating a chrome window), you will want to consider changing your strategy from using a particular concrete type to some interface or abstract class. If you did that, the setup might look something like the below:

```cs
var mockDriver = new Mock<IWebDriver>();
dummyManager.Setup(x => x.CreateRemoteWebDriver(It.IsAny<ChromeOptions>()))
            .Returns(mockDriver.Object);
```

Comment: appreciate the help. I cannot use RemoteWebDriver because that's a concrete class that will create undesirable effects as you mentioned. The solution you provided makes sense, but now I'm getting an interesting error "'Unable to cast object of type 'Castle.Proxies.IWebDriverProxy' to type 'OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver'.'" Which makes sense and makes me wonder, how would I cast a mock?

Comment: If you haven't changed the implementation class, it's not surprising that you would get a cast error. If possible, you should remove the cast to RemoteWebDriver and make your methods rely on the interface (IWebDriver). If you really need a RemoteWebDriver, well, you don't have much choice but to use that type.

Behind the scenes, mocks just subclass the mocked type (or implement it, for interfaces). If a cast from IWebDriver to RemoteWebDriver wouldn't succeed normally (say, for a different impl), it won't work for the mock either.

Comment: I've gotta cast to RemoteWebDriver to get access to it's code. It also works in the other test that's my control. There's a line where I cast. Also, I added RemoteWebDriver class to my question so that you can look at it.

Comment: Actually, I take that back. That cast to RemoteWebDriver was redundant in the test code. But it works in the Start() as expected

Comment: In your working example, you really do create an instance of RemoteWebDriver, so a cast there will obviously succeed.


If you both _need_ a concrete instance of RemoteWebDriver, but don't _want_ to create an instance of it, then this is a dissonance that you'll need to resolve before you can consider doing tests on that method. The Moq library can't create them by magic.


It's possible that the methods you intend to test are also defined on the interfaces that RemoteWebDriver implements. It's worth checking if one of them would work as a return value instead.